# rails routing action new to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I setup some routes like so:

resources :stormtroopers, :only => [:show, :index, :update, :edit]

I suspected that the new action when I hit the url '/stormtroopers/new' would not be available, however the show action is trying to look up the id 'new'

my rspec test says it all

expected {:get=>"/stormtroopers/new"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stormtroopers", :id=>"new"}

is this correct behavior on rails part?  I don't think its my route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no route anymore for your `new` action because you removed it.

But the show action is looking for `/stormtroopers/something`. With no constraint on `something`.

That's why it matches this route and triggers this action.

Usually, the `resources` defines internally `new` before `show` and that works because the rule in routing is: first matched, first served.

So it's just logic, clear?

Comment: I figured that, but I am more curious if this is what it should be doing?  I guess my thought was if I am not declaring the new action, then should routing still try and route it using show? Apparently so.

Comment: the main point is define the new route before the show route, thanks